# Advice on what to put on my home page

Tags: website-design, images, page-layout, website-templates

I need a little help, and general advice, on what I can put on the front page of my software company's website. I realise that this question is not as specific as some may like it to be, but I hoped that someone here would be able to point me in the right direction any how. I have a theme/template to work around which I do not really want to change for various reasons. I have created a rough 'drawing' of what the homepage currently looks like.
[image: Rough mock up of my website template/theme]

As you can see, I have a table of reasons as to why people should purchase our software which I am quite happy with, however I think that it looks quite bare, so what else should I put there. I have expiremented with a slider, with some  clipart to the left of some text, but for some reason it looked out of place. I think it was partly due to the clipart I was using.

However, since trying sliders I have read that a lot of people are stopping using them because they are not actually effective, and are switching to they static images instead. So does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should put on my front page? What would you expect?

I currently have two pieces of software for Windows and Mac and a support ticketing system. Though, I do plan on releasing more software for Windows, Linux, Mac, iOS, Android and maybe WP. My 'motto' is along the lines of great minds think alike. If that helps your ideas in any way.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I don't understand the question and think you're going to get closed if you don't edit it significantly. Are you trying to figure out what content belongs on the main page or just how to do something specific? As it stands your question is very vague and has little to nothing related to graphic design in it. It also confuses me that you say you need help with the design and don't have an eye for it but then say your theme is a winner.

Comment: @Ryan Ok. Firstly, I think I've made a winner and personally I like it but if anybody disagrees and wants to pick fault at it they can be my guest. Basically, yes I'm trying to figure out what I should put on the front page of my site. Does a content slider belong on there or not do you think? If you do think I should put a content slider on there, can you suggest how it should look so that it blends in with the the theme I have and doesn't look out out of place please

Comment: Sorry but to be honest, as it stands, this sounds more like a job than a question. You could improve it and get a useful answer if you focus on content sliders - maybe something along the lines of, "Under what circumstances do content sliders fit with and complement a web page? Here's an example where it doesn't work. Why?". But right now, it crosses the line between solving general design problems, and asking for free work specific for one project. Re. content sliders, here's a link that might help: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/09/slideshows-in-web-design-when-and-how-to-use-them/

Comment: @user568458 I have now edited the question completely so hopefully it will be more answerable. I must admit it does sound a bit like a job but let me assure you, it is not meant to. Really, I just want people's ideas please. I don't think I can say much more really. I will admit it is help for a specific project and may not help anybody else, but this is a question and answers forum isn't it? I don't see why this question would not fit here

Comment: @Andy Please refer to the community FAQ, it will explain why for multiple reasons this question is not a good fit here. For one thing it is not related to graphic design, for another it is a brainstorming question and to drive the point home you just said yourself that it won't benefit anyone else: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @Ryan Ok - yes. Maybe this question does not strictly fit here according to the FAQ, but I can't agree that this question isn't related to graphic design. I was able to add the appropriate tags to this question, and I would have thought the fact that the tags I wanted were available would mean that it is alright to ask such questions. So I'll hold my hand up and admit that I probably should have never asked it here, but since I did and whilst it's not closed, can't we bend the rules just this once and help me out here?

Comment: And if this isn't the place for such questions, does anybody know of any websites where I *can* ask such a question. Preferably with fast response times and as quality answers as we get here.

Comment: This is really more of a UX/Business Analysis type question. Before you design, you need to come up with objectives for the design. What is the primary purpose of this site? What content will help achieve that purpose? Once you have that, THEN the graphic design part can be started.

Comment: @DA01 Thank you very much for your comment too. Those questions did make me think a lot and they have helped my to create a new web design that I am now happy with

Answer (score 3):

The brainstorming process you are going through right now is normal. It is hard to answer your question with so little information about your company, your customers, your target, your whole business. In fact when done correctly, the process is long and deep, and often (if not always) requires a professional expertise.

That said, I think what would help is actually looking at other companies websites, maybe your competitor (not to actually do exactly the same but it can clear part of the confusion your are having at this point of the process). Once this done, I'm sure your questions will be specific enough so people here can actually answer them.

Also, have a look at this little [infographic](http://www.choblab.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/web-design-home-page-fortune500.png) and maybe try this [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dont-Make-Me-Think-Usability/dp/0321344758), which is a reference when it comes to web design and usability. I hope it's going to help.

Comment: sorry for the slow reply and thank you for your answer, especially the links. I have been looking at a few other websites and I have been able to combine some of them to produce a website design that I think I'm now very happy with. I can now see why this process is most often done by professionals now though :')